# Releasing minor Sharepoint Designer change to Sharepoint 2007 production site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Post-release, I have made one small change to one form in our development site in Sharepoint Designer. Is there a way of releasing a change to one form into Production without doing an entire STSADM web site restore ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell whar type of change you made?

Comment: I updated a Custom List form that contained an incorrect variable name, so its not something I can fix with a Content Editor Web Part if that was your thinking..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page that you have updated in SharePoint Designer is just a page in a document library.  So you download it from the document library (or from SharePoint Designer) and then upload it to replace the current version in the same document library in production.

Basically, you just need to do a copy/paste of the file from your test server to your production server.

Comment: I've been a bit stupid - didnt realise I had edit rights to the prod server as a result of having Owner priviledges . Thanks for pointing me in the right direction !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use Reset to site definition button on items context menu.

[SPD Context menu http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/9897/ss20100316120341.png](http://img697.imageshack.us/img697/9897/ss20100316120341.png)

Comment: I should have been more clear - I wish to release one page only to production rather than the entire site..